# How do i update to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: updates

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04. I want to update to 16.04. But the Software updater does not show the required update. How do i update?

Comment: Wait some more hours

Comment: Don't. At least not yet. I did it and lost like 8 hours of my live getting my system working again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that your software is up to date. (run update manager)
Than open the terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run this command

`sudo update-manager -d`

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and enter your password when asked.

Of course, be sure to make backup of any important data. It should not alter them, but you never know.

Comment: Official instructions found here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes

Comment: Don't do this, unless you want the development release! (As of the 21st of April, 09:34 UTC)

Answer (score 0):

In order to upgrade your distribution you may give this a try:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

As the manual page itself explains:

> ```
>    dist-upgrade
>        dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade,
>        also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions
>        of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and
>        it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the
>        expense of less important ones if necessary.
> ```

It'll upgrade the distro to its latest version.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to upgrade to 15.10, then you can upgrade to 16.04.

From a terminal window:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Reboot if asked.

3. `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Answer questions and reboot as required.  Now you should be at 15.10

4. `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Answer questions and reboot as required.  Now you should be at 16.04